# Area of ellipses centred at different points

Tags: integration

How could you prove that the area of an ellipse centred at (0,0) equals the area of the same ellipse centred at a different point? It is about using properties of the Riemann integral, but I don't know how to compare them in terms of integrals of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change of variables:

\begin{align}
  \xi &= x+h \\
  \eta &= y+k \\
  \iint_{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}<1} dy \, dx &= 
  \int_{-a}^{a} \int_{-b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}^{b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}} \, dy \, dx  \\&=
\int_{-a+h}^{a+h} \int_{k-b\sqrt{1-\frac{(\xi-h)^2}{a^2}}}^{k+b\sqrt{1-\frac{(\xi-h)^2}{a^2}}} \, d\eta \, d\xi \\
  &= \iint_{\frac{(\xi-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(\eta-k)^2}{b^2}<1} \, d\eta \, d\xi
\end{align}

Comment: Although it is undoubtedly correct, I think the problem requires the use of one-variable integrals...